# The product of the real part of the roots of $Z^2-Z$=$5-5i$ is....?

Tags: complex-numbers

> The product of the real part of the roots of $Z^2-Z$=$5-5i$ is....?

We can use the quadratic formula and find the two roots and then find the required product, but that is a bit lengthy procedure.

Can you give me hints to solve this question in a shorter way?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;\Delta = 21 - 20 i = (5-2i)^2\,$, and $\operatorname{Re}(z_{1,2})=\cfrac{1 \pm \operatorname{Re}(\sqrt{\Delta})}{2}$.